# How can I make a message bubble in list view just like Whatsapp does?

Tags: android, listview, popup

I am creating a chat app. When I long press a message, I want some choices to show up. I don't have any idea to do this. Can someone can help me, please?

example of chat app

[image]

Comment: Try simply implements OnLongClickListener and addView for this

Comment: But how can I define the view position.

Comment: Maybe modify the listitem layout with a view of that with marginTop of negative value and simply apply visibility change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this task use ActionMode ([guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu))

Comment: This seems too complicated.

Comment: Absolutely not. You have to implement three steps (see quide): 1) menu in res xml; 2) interface ActionMode.Callback; 3) call startActionMode() in onLongClickListener.

Comment: OK. I will try it latter on. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

may this this will helps you.. By only use of Contextual Actionbar you can achieve this..
http://www.technotalkative.com/contextual-action-bar-cab-android/

Are you using Xmpp framework..?? because m also working in this..

Comment: it seems great. But it seems difficult to customize.